# How do you calculate the eigenvector if $2$ of $3$ equations give $0=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
7-\lambda & 12         & -8\\ 
-2        & -3-\lambda  & 4\\ 
0         & 0          & 3-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}$

The eigenvalue is $\lambda=3$. Calculate the eigenvector.

---

Insert $\lambda=3$ into the matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
4   & 12   & -8\\ 
-2  & -6   & 4\\ 
0   &  0   & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

We get system of equation:

$$I: 4x+12y-8z=0 \Leftrightarrow x+3y-2z=0$$

$$II: -2x-6y+4z=0 \Leftrightarrow x+3y-2z=0$$

$I: x= -3y+2z$

Insert that in $II: -3y+2z+3y-2z=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=0$

So we only have $x=-3y+2z$, awesome..

How can we create an eigenvector with this?

Would it work if we just set some value for $y$ and $z$? I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Yes, you can choose $y$ and $z$ arbitary, as long as one of them is not $0$. Then, you always have a suitable $x$ leading to an eigenvector.

Comment: @Peter So something like that would be a correct eigenvector? $\begin{pmatrix}
-3y+2z\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$, let $ y=z=1$

Comment: Yes, exactly that.Note that $\lambda=3$ is a double-eigenvalue. In this case, there exist two linear independent eigenvectors to this eigenvalue (this is not always the case)

Comment: @Peter but the solution as in previous comment would be correct? Even for a double eigenvalue? Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, because the eigenspace has dimension $2$, we can choose $2$ components arbitary. Your vector is always an eigenvector, unless $y=z=0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calculating the eigenvalues, you may have noticed that $\lambda = 3$ was a double root of the characteristic equation or in other words: it is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2.

This means it is possible that you find two linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to this eigenvalue (that would mean the geometric multiplicity is 2 as well), but this isn't necessarily the case. Your work is fine so far and you end up with:

> So we only have $x=-3y+2z$, awesome..

Now you can freely choose $y$ and $z$ (independently), yielding eigenvectors of the form:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{c} -3y+2z \\ y \\ z\end{array}\right)
=y\left(\begin{array}{c} -3 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right)+z\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$$
This means that any eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $(-3,1,0)$ and $(2,0,1)$. These two are linearly independent so you found 2 eigenvectors; i.e. the geometric multiplicity is 2 as well.

Comment: Oh yeah I got two times the same eigenvalue, $3$. Will it have any effect on calculation of eigenvector? Is it fine if I do it as above and just choose some value for $y, z$ (see my comment)?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix%5B%5B7,12,-8%5D,%5B-2,-3,4%5D,%5B0,0,3%5D%5D) concurs with your answer

Comment: @cnmesr It will have an effect in the sense that in the case of a double eigenvalue, you _expect_ to find either 1 **or** 2 (linearly independent) eigenvectors where in the case of a simple root, you know you will find precisely 1. More generally: if the multiplicity of the eigenvalue is $n$, you will find at most (and up to) $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue.

Comment: Is it alright if I write down just one eigenvector for a double eigenvalue?

Comment: It depends on what the exact question or purpose is, but generally this would probably not be sufficient. I expect you need to find _all_ eigenvectors.

Comment: @StackTD: What you really need to find is all _eigenspaces_, which in general one does by giving a basis for each eigenspace. In eigenspaces of dimension $1$ it means choosing an eigenvector, and eigenspaces of dimension $k$ it means choosing $k$ linearly dependent eigenvectors. In both cases there is choice, though more so in the latter case. Talking about "all eigenvectors" is confusing, since one never actually gives them all (though one can describe them all).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen What you really need to find, depends on the question. I'm not even sure OP has heard about _eigenspaces_ - I can't tell. If he copied the question literally, it says _"Calculate **the** eigenvector."_ which is confusing as well. By _all_, I meant a maximal number of linearly independent ones (see earlier comment).

Comment: Can i use any value for y, z? but that will lead to different vectors!

Answer (score 3):

you can choose any non zero vector parallel to the plane $x+3y-2z=0$ to be an eigenvector.

This situation arises whenever the characteristic equation has a double root. in this case the characteristic equation is $$(3-\lambda)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-1)=0$$

So any two independent vectors parallel to the plane can be taken as eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $3$

Comment: Can you please give an example how a possible solution would look? I'm confused if I now really need two eigenvectors because of the double root.

Comment: just assign for example $y=1$ and $z=1$ and get $x=-1$

Comment: That means in case of a double root, the calculation of eigenvector will be done the same way as of a "single" eigenvalue? So in this example something like this would be a correct eigenvector? $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Not "_whenever_ the characteristic equation has a double root". In fact (unless there is a special reason like a symmetric real matrix) most the the time this does **not** happen for multiple roots. However instructors seem to be very fond of this special case; it turns up all the time in exercises.